# Xamarin: Error trying to show WebView using OpenLayers maps with html and javascript

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, openlayers

I'm trying to show a map in xamarin using a WebView component, 
try passing this code to an html file and it works fine.  The WebView is from Xamarin.Forms

The line `alert('test');` 
and the word App in the body of the html is shown without problems, but the map doesn't show.

The devise for test was running android 9

```
    var browser = new WebView();
    browser.HeightRequest = 600;
    browser.WidthRequest = 600;

    var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
    htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
                           <head>
                              <script src='http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js'></script>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                 App
                                  <div id='mapdiv'></div>
                                  <script>
                                       alert('test');  
                                       map = new OpenLayers.Map('mapdiv');
                                       map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

                                       var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1279688, 51.5077286)
                                      .transform(
                                       new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), 
                                       map.getProjectionObject() 
                                    );

                                      var zoom = 16;

                                      var markers = new 
                                      OpenLayers.Layer.Markers('Markers');
                                      map.addLayer(markers);

                                      markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

                                      map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
                                </script>
                      </body></html>";

                    browser.Source = htmlSource;
                    Children.Add(browser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: Change your script link use `https` (vs. `http`)

2nd: The `OpenLayers.js` script itself uses a lot of non-secure links and that is a problem on iOS and new Android API levels from Google as by default all links should be secure (`https`).

If you review the application output you will see log messages such as:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

#### iOS:

So on iOS, you will have to add an exception to your app's Info.plist such as:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/4984832

#### Android:

> Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

On Android 9+ you will have add a security exception to your app (`cleartextTrafficPermitted`)

re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997456/4984832

Note: My Xamarin-based answer is linked, or edit the manifest directly via the other answers to that question.

**BTW: The ultimate answer would be to file a bug with OpenLayers to use secure endpoints in all their scripts so application security exceptions do not have to be applied for...**

Comment: It's work, thanks, but there is other way to implement OpenLayers in xamarin, I search for  some good libraries in nugets repository without results. 
I want  an alternative to google maps

Comment: @lucianocba OpenLayers/OpenStreetMap have Rest-API endpoints (that is what their JS libraries use) so you "could" write a C#/Xamarin interface/frontend, but not sure that is worth the effort (of course I do not know your app's requirements)... There are projects such as OsmSharp, but I not used any of them, just the javascript/browser interface.

Comment: There's point in filing a bug report with OpenLayers for that library, it's version 2 last updated in 2013.  The next release will be version 6.